# Как в Yii2 leftJoin задать as для таблицы?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

У меня есть такой запрос

```
$rows = $rows->leftJoin('object_row_values', 'object_row_values.data=object_data.id')
                    ->andFilterWhere([
                    'AND',
                    ['object_row_values.row' => $key],
                    ['LIKE', 'object_row_values.value', $value]
                ]);
```

Как мне сделать, что бы в запросе писало

```
object_row_values as t1
```

И потом уже подставляло t1?

Comment: `leftJoin('object_row_values as t1', 't1.data=object_data.id')` ?

Comment: @Akina в доке написано что as не надо, просто через пробел

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49475019/10138734

Comment: @Akina https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record#relation-table-aliases

Comment: @Dmitriy Можно не использовать, можно использовать. "Hе надо" - слишком категорично... и потому в общем неверно. Стандарт SQL оставляет этот вопрос - использовать или нет,- на откуп программисту.

Comment: @Akina согласен с вами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начиная с версии 2.0.7 вот так

```
$rows = $rows->leftJoin('object_row_values t1', 't1.data=object_data.id')
                    ->andFilterWhere([
                    'AND',
                    ['t1.row' => $key],
                    ['LIKE', 't1.value', $value]
                ]);
```